# Simplify $\ln(e^{2x+1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to do an integration problem with u sub and got stuck, one part of the equation was this
$\ln(e^{2x+1})$

this is suppose to simplify really nicely according to a site, is there a rule for this i get that $\ln(e) =1$ and that $\ln(e^{x})=x$. So would $\ln(e^{2x+1})=2x+1$? Is this a rule that I may have forgotten about? I'm more interested in the properties behind this if it is a rule, just out of curiosity as to why it is so.

Comment: yes $\ln (e^{f(x)})=f(x)$

Comment: thanks! i've been searchign for this rule, but couldn't find it

Comment: It's like $g \circ g^{-1}(x)=x$  the kind of general rule

Comment: Indeed, note that the map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^+\cup\{0\}$ defined by $x\mapsto e^x$ is bijective with the explicit inverse function $\Bbb R^+\cup\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto\ln(x)$, so we have $\ln(e^x)=x~\forall~x\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it this way: $\ln(e^{f(x)})$ defines the exponent such that if you take $e$ to the power of that exponent, will equal to $f(x)$. So, what power does $e$ need to be raised to for it to equal to $e$ to the power of $f(x)$? $f(x)$ itself, of course, and this works for any exponent since we made no assumptions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the natural logarithm(ln) of a number is its logarithm(log) to the base of the mathematical constant e.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln(e^{2x+1})=2x+1$$
Take exponential on both side
$$e^{\ln(e^{2x+1})}=e^{2x+1}$$
but $e^{\ln a}=a$ , so: 
$$e^{2x+1}=e^{2x+1}$$
You have these rules
$$
\begin{cases}
e^{\ln (f(x))}=f(x) \\
\ln(e^{f(x)})=f(x)
\end{cases}
$$